# Need more insights in listen system call linux

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp, system-calls

```
int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);
```

Here is a description form linux man page

listen()  marks  the  socket referred to by sockfd as a passive socket,
       that is, as a socket that will be used to  accept  incoming  connection
       requests using accept(2).

The  sockfd  argument  is  a file descriptor that refers to a socket of
       type SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET.

The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the  queue  of
       pending  connections  for  sockfd  may  grow.   If a connection request
       arrives when the queue is full, the client may receive an error with an
       indication  of  ECONNREFUSED  or,  if  the underlying protocol supports
       retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt at
       connection succeeds.

The thing which bug me alot is why do we actually need to call listen.Is it to make the server start listening to the binded address and port.Isn't it the case that as soon as an address and port is binded to the socket descriptor the client can simply connect to that binded address.Thinks get more confusing when we don't make the listen call during the creation of an UDP server,does the UDP server automatically start listening as soon as an address is binded to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A host can receive packets from anywhere at any time. With TCP, before you call `listen` the operating system responds to any arriving packet with an RST packet. After `listen` it will reply to SYN packets with a SYN-ACK packet, and adds information about the remote side to the list of pending "connections", and the connection is now established.

With UDP there are no connections. If an application is waiting for a UDP packet and one arrives, the operating system passes the packet to the app. If no one is expecting packets the OS drops them.

The `bind` function just gives an address for a socket. It's not limited for use in servers, you could use `bind` on client sockets as well to set the IP and port you connect from. It's usually not required, so you don't see it very often.

Comment: so the tcp connection(3 way handshake) is established after the listen system call and not after the accept system call